# Set User logon name (pre-windows 2000) using Powershell Script

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

How do set this variable using powershell?

[image]

```
$firstName = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter first name: "
$lastName = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter last name: "
$username = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter username: "
...


New-ADUser `
-Name $displayName `
-GivenName $firstName `
-Surname $lastName `
-DisplayName $displayName `
-UserPrincipalName $pName `
-AccountPassword(ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force) `
-PasswordNeverExpires $True `
-Description $description `
-EmailAddress $email `
-Path $path `
-Enabled $true
 
 Get-ADUser -Identity $displayName
```

I am trying to write a script for user creation.  I would like to set the user logon name (pre-windows 2000) while I'm running the script and entering thee user information.

Comment: You mean the sAMAccountName? New-ADUser has a [Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/new-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-samaccountname) for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need as include the `-sAMAccountName` attribute. So

```
New-ADUser `
-Name $displayName `
-GivenName $firstName `
-Surname $lastName `
-DisplayName $displayName `
-sAMAccountName $samaccountname `
-UserPrincipalName $pName `
-AccountPassword(ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force) `
-PasswordNeverExpires $True `
-Description $description `
-EmailAddress $email `
-Path $path `
-Enabled $true
 
 Get-ADUser -Identity $displayName
```

Note, keep in mind that the SamAccountName aka "user logon name (pre-windows 2000)" has a maximum character length of 20 characters. So when validating your inputs you probably want to check that the entered value isn't too long, for instance

```
if ($samaccountname.length -gt 20)
{
   Write-Output "Error, entered username is longer than 20 characters"
   break
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Keith!  I tried this before and it was giving me an error for the "Get-ADUser" command.  But I needed to change the Identity from $displayName to $username (since it will be the same) after adding -sAMAccountName.